# Termux PostgreSQL initdb: wrong directory ownership

Tags: shell, termux

Recently, I installed PostgreSQL pkg on Termux. But when I wanted to use the `initdb postgre` command to initialize postgre directory, I had the wrong ownership:

```
$ initdb postgres
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "u0_a691".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "C.UTF-8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory postgres ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... mmap
selecting default max_connections ... 20
selecting default shared_buffers ... 400kB
selecting default time zone ... Iran
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... 
2024-01-05 03:41:58.200 +0330 [21102] FATAL:  data directory "/storage/emulated/0/dev/python/projects/l/L10/db/postgres" has wrong ownership
2024-01-05 03:41:58.200 +0330 [21102] HINT:  The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory.
child process exited with exit code 1
initdb: removing contents of data directory "postgres"
```

But when I used

```
chown u0_a691 postgres
```

ChatGPT said that I should use the group of directory, but I could not use `sudo addgroup mygroup` command because my phone is not rooted, and the second thing I could not do was change file `/etc/group` manually. And that didn't work too. BTW, I can use this command on Termux storage, but I don't really want to use that there. I want to use that on my internal storage and it doesn't work now.

Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0` (aka `/sdcard`) is a bad choice as installation target as this folder uses special mount options, e.g. preventing execution and other things like no direct access in Android 11+. If you want to execute software change target to the Termux app private folder `/data/data/com.termux/files/home`.